# Estou tentando criar uma conexão usando localhost porém está dando connection refused

Tags: android, web-service

```
public static String getJsonSystem(String urlString){

    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    String retorno = "";

    try{
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.connect();

        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());

        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String line = "";
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
            buffer.append(line);
        }

        retorno = buffer.toString();


    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return retorno;
}
```

Aqui como eu chamo a conexão:

```
String caminho = "http://192.168.0.11/system/pages/login";
HttpConnection conexão = new HttpConnection();
String resp = conexão.getJsonSystem(caminho);

AlertDialog.Builder alerta = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
alerta.setMessage(resp);
alerta.show();
```

Comment: Confirme que o servidor que quer conectar está funcionando. Consegue conectar o servidor diretamente no browser usando este URL?

Comment: Verificou se está dando permissão de acesso a internet no seu AndroidManifest? Assim: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Comment: Eu testei a url está conectando.
Quanto a permissão ela já está no meu manifest.

Comment: Dente debugar sua aplicação e ver qual linha está parando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se estiver usando o emulador `AVD` você deve usar `10.0.2.2` para ter acesso ao localhost do seu computador. 
Conforme está descrito na [documentação oficial](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking.html).

Para o emulador `Genymotion` você deve usar `10.0.3.2`.

--Edit

Lembre-se de manter o protocolo `http` no link, no seu caso:

> "http://10.0.2.2/system/pages/login"

Comment: Lucas realizei a troca para 10.0.2.2 como disse já que eu uso AVD;
Ele retornou o seguinte erro:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://10.0.2.2/system/pages/login
W/System.err:     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:521)

Comment: @Felipe Você deve manter o `http://`, assim: `http://10.0.2.2/system/pages/login`, tenta e me diz se deu certo.

Comment: Mantive o http://10.0.2.2/system/pages/login
Porém quando tentei pegar o retorno da frase em Json não converti para String ai gerava um erro.
Sua resposta foi muito eficaz eu agradeço muito por essa ajuda e me proporcionar aumentar mais meu conhecimento.